# Xamarin Forms Using Reflexion to get Property of Bindable Property

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, reflection, bindableproperty

What i want is, when the value is changed, it should call `CreateChart()`and use the new values.
I try to call in an onPropertyChange method `OnValueChanged` a bindable Property with reflection, but the property is always null and i dont get the value of the property `Value`

```
public partial class CorrectWrongRingChart : ContentView
    {
        public CorrectWrongRingChart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            
        }
        
        public static readonly BindableProperty ChartProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(CorrectWrongChart),
                typeof(Chart),
                typeof(CorrectWrongRingChart));

        public Chart CorrectWrongChart
        {
            get { return (Chart)GetValue(ChartProperty); }
            set => SetValue(ChartProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ValueProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(
              nameof(Value),
              typeof(CorrectWrongValue),
              typeof(CorrectWrongRingChart),
              propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);/*(b, o, n) => { ((CorrectWrongRingChart)b).OnPropertyChanged("Text");});*/

        public  CorrectWrongValue Value
        {
            get { return (CorrectWrongValue)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
             ((CorrectWrongRingChart)bindable).OnPropertyChanged("Text");            
             //((CorrectWrongRingChart)bindable).OnPropertyChanged("Correct"); 
             //((CorrectWrongRingChart)bindable).OnPropertyChanged("Wrong");
            var valueProperty = ValueProperty.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
            var value = (CorrectWrongValue)valueProperty.GetValue("Value");
            var ChartProperty = ValueProperty.GetType().GetProperty("CorrectWrongChart");
            
            if (value != null)
            {

                ChartProperty.SetValue("CorrectWrongChart", CreateChart(value));
                
            }
            
            

        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(Text),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CorrectWrongRingChart),
                defaultValue: string.Empty);

        public string Text => $"{Value?.CorrectCount ?? 0}/{Value?.TotalCount ?? 0}";
        //public double Correct => Value.CorrectPercentage;
        //public  double Wrong => Value.WrongPercentage;


        private static Chart CreateChart(CorrectWrongValue value)
        {
            var chart = new Microcharts.DonutChart();
            chart.IsAnimated = false;
            
            ChartEntry corretEntry = new ChartEntry((float)value.CorrectPercentage)
            {
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#00FF00")
            };
            ChartEntry wrongEntry = new ChartEntry((float)value.WrongPercentage)
            {
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#FF0000")
            };
            chart.Entries = new List<ChartEntry>() { corretEntry, wrongEntry };
            return chart;
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid >
            <forms:ChartView x:Name="chart1" WidthRequest="130" HeightRequest="130" Chart="{Binding CorrectWrongChart, Source={x:Reference Root}}">
               
</forms:ChartView>
            <Label Text="{ Binding Text, Source={x:Reference Root} }"                  
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontSize="19"
                   FontFamily="{ StaticResource AppBoldFontFamily }" />
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `Value` when the value is changed , you could get it directly like following

```
private static void OnValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var currentValue = newValue;
   
   // do something you want 
   
    // you could get other property like following 
    // var view = bindable as CorrectWrongRingChart;
    // var currentText = view.Text;


}
```

The property `Value` will change automatically when we change the value of it source .So we don't need to invoke the following lines any more , which maybe will lead to infinite loop .

```
if (value != null)
{

    ChartProperty.SetValue("CorrectWrongChart", CreateChart(value));
                
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It can be so simple =)